# mysql query to fetch record between a specific date

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to fetch the records from database from a specific date. I have a columns `log_date` having `datetime` data type. now I want to get all records which have log date of previous 24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE log_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND NOW()
```

I think that should work, untested though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the BETWEEN statement. If you google on that you will find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `logtable` WHERE `log_date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```